Production deployment of Radzen doesn't appear to include AuthenticationService.Js
i have been working away at a Radzen Studio application for a while and it's now ready to production deploy,
i have been able to built it and run it successfully on my local machine using Radzen Studio. there is no problem there.
i have followed the multi-tenant example https://www.radzen.com/blog/multitenant-blazor-applications/
as i have a need for a common application with multiple customer databases
it's compiling and running but requires testing for multiple environments.
i have built a Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline which builds and deploys the Radzen Server into an azure web app, similar to the manual deploy instructions here
https://www.radzen.com/documentation/blazor/manual-deploy/
when i come to access the deployed site; i hit a http 500 error on AuthenticationService.JS which appears to be missing from /_configuration/.Client
my issue is this is visible in the browser console in dev, but http 500 post production deployment
any thoughts on debugging / solving?
i was expecting it to build and deploy like the development run environment

found the issue;
there are three appsettings files;
appsettings.json
appsettings.development.json
appsettings.production.json

appsettings.json and appsettings.production.json are basically the same with updated values for production configuration
appsettings.development.json includes a JSON element
...
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
...

this was not included in the production appsettings.
after including this, the _configuration/xxx.Client is then rendered just like in development.
i have no idea what it does, but putting that same element into production appsettings has solved the problem
